# Can I stop Emacs from resetting default-directory every time I open a file?

Tags: emacs, directory, editing

I've already asked the same question on [Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/11038/can-i-stop-emacs-from-resetting-default-directory-every-time-i-open-a-file). If it's not permitted, I'm sorry and I will delete the question.

If I:

- Start Emacs in my home directory (`~`)
- Find a file in the `~/Projects/ruby-play` directory with `C-x C-f`
- Try to find another file with `C-x C-f`

The default directory in the file finder will be `~/Projects/ruby-play`.

What I'd like to see is the default directory being `~` still.

Is there a package/hook/Elisp function I should use to make this happen?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you aware that when you are entering a file path, you can simply type `/~/` at any point to ignore everything preceding that point, and start finding from `~/` ? (And similarly with `//` to get to the filesystem root.)

Comment: I am, thank you. However, I'd like to preserve the directory I started Emacs from, not just the home directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to set `initial-default-directory` to `nil`, but then you won't have a default directory at all, not even your home-directory:

```
(setq insert-default-directory nil)
```

If you want your home directory to show up as the default, this cannot be done so easily. When interactively calling `find-file`, this results in a call to `read-file-name` which has a rather complicated default behavior.

Using `setq-default` on `default-directory` doesn't help, as it's value is set when the file of the buffer you're currently seeing is visited.

The only option I see is using your own version of `find-file` like this:

```
(defun my-find-file-read-args (prompt mustmatch)
  (list (read-file-name prompt "~/" nil mustmatch)
    t))

(defun my-find-file (filename &optional wildcards)
  "Edit file FILENAME.
Like `find-file` but always uses ~ as the default directory"
  (interactive
   (my-find-file-read-args "Find file: "
                        (confirm-nonexistent-file-or-buffer)))
  (let ((value (find-file-noselect filename nil nil wildcards)))
    (if (listp value)
    (mapcar 'switch-to-buffer (nreverse value))
      (switch-to-buffer value))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") 'my-find-file)
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you.
Won't `ido-find-file-in-dir` help me as well?

Comment: I don't use ido, so I don't know.